# React-Native AsyncStorage setItem doesnt work?

Tags: javascript, react-native, asyncstorage

I have a question about AsyncStorage..

```
console.log(this.state.UserEmail);
AsyncStorage.setItem('email', JSON.stringify(this.state.UserEmail));
```

the console log logs the user's email perfectly fine, but for some reason when i try to do

```
AsyncStorage.getItem("email").then((res) => { this.setState({username: res })});
```

It seems that the AsyncStorage with the item name of "email" is empty.as it does not return anything if i console.log this.state.username.

Thanks in advance,

Mario

Comment: Are you calling `getItem` immediately after `setItem`? `setItem` is an async function, so it may not be complete immediately after.

Comment: No. I'm calling it further into the application. Could it be because i'm navigating to another view? I wouldnt think so but i'm not sure.

Comment: AsyncStorage.getItem("email").then(async (res) => {
  const val = await res;

  this.setState({username: JSON.parse(val) })
});

Comment: `AsyncStorage.getItem('email').then(async (res) => { const val = await res; this.setState({username: JSON.parse(val) }) });

console.log(this.props.navigation.state.params.id + " " + this.state.typing + " " + this.state.username);`

The params.id works, the this.state.typing works, but the this.state.username does not :/

Comment: what is your project version?

Comment: "react": "16.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.53.3",
    "react-navigation": "1.1.2",

Answer (score 4):

//check it out !

```
state = {
        UserEmail: 'abcd@gmail.com'
      }

async setValue() {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('email', JSON.stringify(this.state.UserEmail));
 }

 async getValue() {
  try {
       const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('email');
         if (value !== null) {
            // We have data!!
            console.log(value);
         }
      } catch (error) {
          // Error retrieving data
    }
 }
```

Comment: I have tried, it's working for me. can you show your portion of code?

Answer (score 0):

```
AsyncStorage.getItem("email").then((res) => { this.setState({username: res })});
```

to:

```
AsyncStorage.getItem("email").then(async (res) => {
  const val = await res;

  this.setState({username: val })
});
```

should wait for response data before doing setState

Comment: Okay.. val is indeed the data i need. Now the thing is, the setState does not seem to work for some reason. I cannot use `console.log(this.state.username);`

Comment: @batuhan can you edit your answer to provide more context for future readers?

Comment: i didnt understand. you can use cb : this.setState({username: val }, () => console.log(this.state.username));
also use toString in setItem: AsyncStorage.setItem('email', this.state.UserEmail.toString()); if not json..